# RANK OVER function in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, partitioning, rank

I'm trying to run this query in Hive to return only the top 10 url which appear more often in the adimpression table.

```
select
        ranked_mytable.url,
        ranked_mytable.cnt

from
        ( select iq.url, iq.cnt, rank() over (partition by iq.url order by iq.cnt desc) rnk
        from
                ( select url, count(*) cnt
                from store.adimpression ai
                        inner join zuppa.adgroupcreativesubscription agcs
                                on agcs.id = ai.adgroupcreativesubscriptionid
                        inner join zuppa.adgroup ag
                                on ag.id = agcs.adgroupid
                where ai.datehour >= '2014-05-15 00:00:00'
                        and ag.siteid = 1240
                group by url
                ) iq
        ) ranked_mytable

where
      ranked_mytable.rnk <= 10

order by
        ranked_mytable.url,
        ranked_mytable.rnk desc

;
```

Unfortunately I get an error message stating:

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10002]: Line 26:23 Invalid column reference 'rnk'
```

I've tried to debug it and until the `ranked_mytable` sub-queries everything goes smooth. I've tried to comment the `where ranked_mytable.rnk <= 10` clause but the error message keep appearing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`RANK OVER` is not the best function to achieve this goal.
A better solution would be to use a combination of `SORT BY` and `LIMIT`. It's true in fact `LIMIT` picks randomly the rows in a table, but this might be avoided if used with the `SORT BY` function. From the [Apache Wiki:](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select#LanguageManualSelect-LIMITClause)

```
-- Top k queries. The following query returns the top 5 sales records wrt amount. 
SET mapred.reduce.tasks = 1 SELECT * FROM sales SORT BY amount
DESC LIMIT 5
```

The query can be re-written in this way:

```
select
        iq.url,
        iq.cnt

from
        ( select url, count(*) cnt
        from store.adimpression ai
          inner join zuppa.adgroupcreativesubscription agcs
            on agcs.id = ai.adgroupcreativesubscriptionid
          inner join zuppa.adgroup ag
            on ag.id = agcs.adgroupid
        where ai.datehour >= '2014-05-15 00:00:00'
          and ag.siteid = 1240
        group by url ) iq

sort by
        iq.cnt desc

limit
        10

;
```

Answer (score 11):

Hive is unable to order by a column that is not in the "output" of a select statement. To fix it, just include that column in the selected columns:

```
select
        ranked_mytable.url,
        ranked_mytable.cnt,
        ranked_mytable.rnk

from
        ( select iq.url, iq.cnt, rank() over (partition by iq.url order by iq.cnt desc) rnk
        from
                ( select url, count(*) cnt
                from store.adimpression ai
                        inner join zuppa.adgroupcreativesubscription agcs
                                on agcs.id = ai.adgroupcreativesubscriptionid
                        inner join zuppa.adgroup ag
                                on ag.id = agcs.adgroupid
                where ai.datehour >= '2014-05-15 00:00:00'
                        and ag.siteid = 1240
                group by url
                ) iq
        ) ranked_mytable

where
      ranked_mytable.rnk <= 10

order by
        ranked_mytable.url,
        ranked_mytable.rnk desc

;
```

If you don't want that 'rnk' column in your final output, I expect you could wrap that whole thing in another inner-query and just select out the 'url' and 'cnt' fields.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Joe! Add the `rnk` variable in the results solves the error I got. Unfortunately it doesn't limit the results to the top 10 rows. A better solution would be use `SORT BY` and `LIMIT` in combination.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the *partition by iq.url* clause from rank over() and re-run query.

Thanks & Regards,
Kamleshkumar Gujarathi

Answer (score -1):

Put `as` before the `rnk` variable. It should work fine.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try to provide more explanation to your answers. You should post the corrected code, at least that section. See [How to answer page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for help in improving your answer.